# chaning the join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables, faq and faq_categories...i have a join that work, and so far, I was a happy camper.

But...requirements change, and i have to change the join, but i don't know how to do it

Here is the current code that works just fine:

```
SELECT faq.* , faq_categories.categoryname 
                                  FROM faq 
                                  JOIN faq_categories
                                  ON ( faq.catid = faq_categories.catid)
```

So far, all faq belongs to one category...but from now on, there will be faq which will not belonng to any category....and that complicate things, at least for me.

How should I change this code in order to display the faq which does not have catid?

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faq_categories` (
`catid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`categoryname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`categoryname_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text,
`description_en` text,
`metatags` text,
`metatags_en` text,
`sorder` int(11) NOT NULL,
`visible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`categoryphoto` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`catid`),
KEY `parentid_fk` (`parentid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=204 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faq` (
`faqid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`catid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`question` text NOT NULL,
`question_en` text NOT NULL,
`answer` text,
`answer_en` text,
`metatags` text,
`metatags_en` text,
`sorder` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`visible` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`faqid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that have no category, we assume you mean `faq.catid` will be `NULL. Your table definitions don't need to change at all. That will only require changing your`INNER JOIN`to a`LEFT JOIN`. The FAQs with no category will show a`NULL`for`faq_categories.categoryname` in the output:

```
SELECT 
  faq.* , 
  faq_categories.categoryname 
FROM
  faq 
  LEFT JOIN faq_categories  ON ( faq.catid = faq_categories.catid)
```

I would encourage you now to anticipate the time when a FAQ must belong to more than one category, however.  To do that, you need to create a joining table which contains a `faqid` and `catid`. There can be many rows per `faqid`:

```
CREATE TABLE faq_in_categories (
  faqid INT(11) NOT NULL,
  catid INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (faqid, catid),
  FOREIGN KEY (faqid) REFERENCES faq (faqid),
  FOREIGN KEY (catid) REFERENCES faq_categories (catid)
);
```

Under this model, you would remove the `faq.catid` column because membership in a category is defined in the joining table. This is a *many-to-many relationship*.

Queried by:

```
SELECT 
  faq.*
  categories.*
FROM
  faq
  JOIN faq_in_categories ON faq.faqid = faq_in_categories.faqid
  JOIN categories ON faq_in_categories.catid = categories.catid
WHERE faq.faqid = 'some faqid'
```

Comment: Thanks Michael..that did it. I will accept your answer as soon as system alow me to do so. Thanks.